# Would this question be acceptable or too subjective?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I think that some science fiction gangster characters were especially good by Ronny Cox (Vilos Cohaagen), Clarence Bodicker (by Kurtwood Smith) and some performances by Ron Silver (in the Arrival and Timecop). I wonder if there are some more performances like that e.g. science fiction ganster bosses.

Could such a question remain and get answered or does it not meet standards?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per the "close reasons":

***Requests for lists of works or recommendations are off-topic as they do not fit our questions and answers format.***

It would also seem to fall foul of the FAQ regarding suitable questions;

***You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.***